# For loop vs Sapply in terms of fault step in R

Tags: r, for-loop, sapply

I am facing with a problem when analysing errors in `sapply` in R.

Suppose I have a matrix as below,

```
B <- matrix( 
  c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7), 
  nrow=3, 
  ncol=2)
```

Just to create some errors, I'am indexing out of the bounds of the matrix. (`i in 1:5` part)

```
for (i in 1:5) {

    x <- B[1,i]^2
    if(i==1) {

        result <- x

    }else{

        result <- rbind(result,x)

    }
}
```

Of course it gives an error like this.

```
Error in B[1, i] : subscript out of bounds
```

However, it is not so hard  to find at what step it gives an error.Since, if I call i;

```
> i
[1] 3
```

I can easily understand at what step I have faced with the error.In this case it is happening when `i=3`.

However, to take advantage of the speed of the `sapply` function in R (since the loops are not recommended because of the lack of speed) I used it as below;

```
sapply(1:5 ,function(j) {

       y <- B[1,j]^2

})
```

Not surprisingly it gives the same error.

```
Error in B[1, j] : subscript out of bounds
```

However, now I cannot see at what step I failed. Since neither `j` nor `y` is recorded!

```
> j
Error: object 'j' not found
> y 
Error: object 'y' not found
```

What Can you suggest about that? I know it is a simple example. But the things I am dealing with in reality are more complex and it becomes harder to find the error step.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add a `print` like `sapply(1:5 ,function(j) {
  y <- B[1,j]^2;
  print(j)
})`. The speed issue is here not the point. Of course you can use a loop instead of sapply.

Comment: @Jimbou but in that case, it assigns the print(j) value as for the result of the sapply output. My point is not loosing the real result which is y in this case.

Comment: Then delete it after you fixed your sapply. Or go back to a loop.

Comment: If its more complex to the point you need error handling, you could handle the error within the function you are applying over. at the start of the function you could have an if ncol(B) > j dont try to do the step

Comment: @ChrisLittler It is a general question about sapply function. My problem is not related with ncol()  etc. The problem is actually about surprising errors when using sapply.

Comment: Before `y <- B[1,j]^2` you can add `jj <<- j`, and `jj` will be accessible.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thank you very much. I haven't know the usage of the double arrow (<<-). It works fine!

Answer (score 1):

If you use RStudio, the easiest way is to activate in the Menu: Debug > On Error > Break in code.

This will open a browser on error and you will be able to see the value of j.

If you don't use RStudio, you can set `options(error = recover)` which will also open a browser on error. (In your specific case choose frame 3 and you will be able to see the value of j)